# Unable to start the emulator by running react-native run-android command

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

can anyone help me with this please? I try to run "react-native run-android" but there is an error "Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`". I already started the emulator by Android Studio. I tried to run the app in android studio and it can run fine but I can't start from "react-native run-android command". Thanks a lot.

full command prompt message:

[Error Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bue1.png)

Comment: Please try npx react-native run-android.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it doesn't work. I was able to run the app from the AVD manually and it was refresh to reflect my changes but it still showing error and not start automatically by "react-native run-android" or "npx react-native run-android" command.